# Start a terminal in OSX Lion in order to upgrade OS from dock

Tags: macos

i want to upgrade my `OSX Lion` to `Mavericks` and install from USB dock.
I found [this](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57608836-285/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-mavericks-usb-install-drive/) article that explain how to do that but since i am not familiar with `OSX` i don't know even how to open terminal.

Comment: Click on the spotlight icon, (upper right corner) and start typing "terminal", it will find the application for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Terminal is located in /Applications/Utilities/, however do beware that this is a very powerful tool that you shouldn't mess around with too much if you don't know what you are doing. The easiest and recommended way to install Mavericks is still through the App store.